# makefile for c++ compilation not running

Tags: c++, makefile

I've made a makefile to compile program `calc.cpp`:

```
SRCS=calc.cpp
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))
FLGS=-std=c++17

all: calc clean

calc:
        g++ $(SRCS) $(FLGS) -o $(OBJS)
        ./calc.o

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS)
```

However, I'm getting some strange errors:

- when I `make all`, it only prints `rm -f calc.o`
- if I remove `clean` section from `all`, it prints `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`
- when I `make calc`, it prints `make: 'calc' is up to date.`

What is going on here, and why does `make calc` not compile my code?

Comment: Consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile` (at least on POSIX and Linux). BTW, you want `-Wall -Wextra` in your `FLGS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule:

```
calc:
         ...
```

tells make how a target `calc` can be built and that it has no prerequisites.  This means that if the file exists, make considers it up to date (how else, since it doesn't depend on anything)?

So presumably you have a file named `calc` already existing in your directory, so when you run `make calc` make thinks it's up to date.

You have to list some prerequisites of `calc` if you want make to do something more than try to build the target if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This makefile has various issues.  For example if you ever try to add more than one source file to your `SRCS` variable it will break badly.

Comment: Does make automatically map multiple $(SRCS) with $(OBJS) as mentioned in the makefile above?

Comment: @MadScientist why would the makefile break in this scenario?

Comment: Also you seem to be using the extension `.o` for _executable_ files.  While of course POSIX systems have no naming mandated, you're flouting 50 years of tradition which says that `.o` files are _object_ files, which are not executable.  If you want others to understand what you're doing it's better to stick with tradition unless there's some very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Say `SRCS = a.cpp b.cpp`.  Then `OBJS` will be `a.o b.o`  Then your compile rule in your recipe will expand to `g++ a.cpp b.cpp -std=c++17 -o a.o b.o` which won't do what you want, and GCC will probably throw an error.